# Obtener IP local en C# en UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

¿Cómo se puede obtener la ip del dispositivo en C#?
Que funcione en el ámbito de las UWP (Universal Windows Plataform) conocidas como aplicaciones universales de windows10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes preguntar por el perfil de conexión a internet, luego verificar cual es el adaptador de red actual que coincide con el perfil.

Ten en cuenta que debes validar muchas cosas, como si existen o no dispositivos, o si existe más de uno. Incluso puede existir el dispositivo pero sino estas conectado a una red. Etc.

Utiliza este método para encontrar la IP local que ya tiene todo implementado.

```
    private string GetLocalIp()
    {
        var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        //sino hay disp de red devuelve null
        if (icp?.NetworkAdapter == null) return null;

        var hostname = (from hn in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
                       where hn.IPInformation?.NetworkAdapter != null
                          && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                          == icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                       select hn).First();


        return hostname?.CanonicalName;
    }
```

Con este otro método (abajo) puedes hallar la dirección con la que sale a internet, la cual no es la misma IP local . `NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()` devuelve una lista de interfaces algunas con IP, en todo caso el orden de estas interfaces es .

- IP

  - Interfaces sin IP
  - Interfaces con IP
- Tipo de red

  - Externas
  - Locales

por lo que este método retorna con la primera interfaz con IP externa.

```
    private string GetIp()
    {
        string ip = string.Empty;

        var ll = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().ToList();

        foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
        {
            if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
            {
                if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
                {
                    ip = localHostName.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: Entiendo que GetInternetConnnectionProfile es el perfil que tiene acceso a internet, con lo cual ya resuelve mi propósito.

Comment: Hola, así es. Pero no es la IP que sale a internet, es la IP local. La segunda opción que he puesto, basada en la respuesta de @MBahamondes devuelve la IP de internet (al menos en mis pruebas)

Answer (score 5):

Acá puedes mirar documentación de la API : [Windows.Networking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx)

Prueba con este código:

```
string ip;
foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
{
    if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
    {
        if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
        {
            ip = localHostName.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta tambien funciona, pero el tuyo reporta la IP con que sale a internet, el mio reporta la IP Local. He complementado mi respuesta con eso